# How can I use *ngIf directive to change an image?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm developing an application with the technologies shown below. How can i use *ngIf directive to change an image with another one? I will be more precise in explaining my intentions; I've two images (male symbol ♂ and female symbol ♀), when I've 'gender == M' I have to display male symbol, instead when I've 'gender == F' I have to display feminin symbol. Thanks to everyone!

**Technologies that I currently use:**

- Ionic 4.10.2
- Angular 6
- 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- TypeScript
- Visual Studio Code

Comment: and how your code looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I solved,

```html
<img *ngIf="response.gender == 'F'" src="female.png" slot="start" />
<img *ngIf="response.gender == 'M'" src="male.png" slot="start" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below

```
<img src="gender == 'M'? 'your image path for male': 'your image path for Female'"/>
```

using above no need to use ngIf directive

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<img [src]="gender == 'M' ? 'path1' : 'path2'"/>` or `<img src="{{gender == 'M' ? 'path1' : 'path2'}}" />` for angular to accept the interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using images you can go for font awesome icons

```
<div *ngIf="gender == 'F'; else elseBlock">
  <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true">
  </i>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true">
  </i>
</ng-template>
```